# Javascript only works when Web Inspector is open in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have some javascript that creates a justified gallery and changes the positions of some of the elements. This works in all browsers apart from Safari. However, if I open the Web Inspector then the javascript works correctly and the gallery functions. I can close the Web Inspector, refresh the page and it still works correctly.

Here is the javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  if (jQuery('#gallery-2')) {
    jQuery('#gallery-2').attr('id', '');
  }

  let parent = document.querySelector('.justified_gallery .gallery');
  let children = parent.querySelectorAll('.justified_gallery .gallery-item');
  let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className = 'swiper-wrapper';

  children.forEach((childe) => {
    wrapper.appendChild(childe);
    childe.classList.add('swiper-slide');
  });

  let container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = 'swiper-containere';

  container.prepend(wrapper);

  parent.prepend(container);

  let pagination = document.createElement('div');
  pagination.className = 'swiper-paginatione';
  container.prepend(pagination);

  var swipere = new Swiper('.swiper-containere', {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 3000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 12,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-paginatione',
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swipee-right',
      prevEl: '.swipee-left',
    },
  });

  jQuery('.gallery-item>div').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).after("<h4>" + jQuery('a', this).attr('data-elementor-lightbox-title') + "</h4>");
  })
  jQuery('.gallery-item').each(function() {
    width = jQuery("img", this).css("width");
    jQuery(this).css("width", width);
  })

  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    updateContainer();
  });

});

function updateContainer() {
  var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
  var itemWidth = jQuery('.swiper-slide-active').width();
  var left = ((windowWidth / 2) + (itemWidth / 2)) - 60 + 'px';
  var right = (windowWidth - ((windowWidth / 2) + (itemWidth / 2))) - 10 + 'px';
  jQuery('.swipee-left').css("left", left);
  jQuery('.swipee-right').css("right", right);
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6a873da justified_gallery elementor-widget elementor-widget-image-gallery" data-id="6a873da" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image-gallery.default">
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-image-gallery">
        <div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-2 gallery-columns-1 gallery-size-medium_large'>
            <figure class='gallery-item'>
                <div class='gallery-icon portrait'>
                    <a data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes" data-elementor-lightbox-slideshow="6a873da" data-elementor-lightbox-title="77 Newman Street, W1" href='https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1.jpg'>
                    <noscript><img width="768" height="1152" src="https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-768x1152.jpg" class="attachment-medium_large size-medium_large" alt="TW 001 1" aria-describedby="gallery-1-886" srcset="https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-768x1152.jpg 768w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-200x300.jpg 200w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-683x1024.jpg 683w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-1024x1536.jpg 1024w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1.jpg 1200w" sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px"></noscript>
                    <img width="768" height="1152" src='data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20768%201152%22%3E%3C/svg%3E' data-src="https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-768x1152.jpg" class="lazyload attachment-medium_large size-medium_large" alt="TW 001 1" aria-describedby="gallery-1-886" data-srcset="https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-768x1152.jpg 768w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-200x300.jpg 200w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-683x1024.jpg 683w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1-1024x1536.jpg 1024w, https://warrenre.webpi.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TW_001-1.jpg 1200w" data-sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <figcaption class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='gallery-1-886'> Advised one of the London Estates on the Investment Purchase</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6fda481 swipee-left elementor-widget__width-auto elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="6fda481" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
        <div class="elementor-icon"> <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-af4ebc9 swipee-right elementor-widget__width-auto elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="af4ebc9" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
        <div class="elementor-icon"> <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A test version of the page can be viewed here: https://warrenre.webpi.co

The gallery is right at the bottom after the 'PREVIOUS TRANSACTIONS' title.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are you mixing DOM access and jQuery? That makes it harder to maintain

Comment: I made you a snippet. Can you add relevant HTML so we have a [mcve] here instead on a site that disappears or gets fixed

Comment: Thank you. HTML added with only one image in the gallery to keep it minimal.

Comment: @mplungjan - I'm not sure why I'm mixing DOM access and jQuery - how does that make it harder to maintain? Is there any other reason not to do that?

Comment: It makes it confusing to read. Also if you do not have conflicts, use the $ instead of jQuery prefix for readability

Comment: @mplungjan Ah, I see. There are conflicts stopping me from using $ instead of jQuery.